# I need the backup name to include today's date when using MSSQL RDS backups

Tags: sql, sql-server, amazon-s3, backup, amazon-rds

I am creating a stored procedure that is making backups straight from RDS MSSQL to S3. I need the backup name that gets placed in S3 to include today's date, thus, I need to include a Parameter (@NOW) in the name.

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[USP_DatabaseFullBackup]
AS
DECLARE @NOW DATETIME,        
@SERVERNAME VARCHAR(100) 

SET @NOW = (SELECT GETDATE())
SET @SERVERNAME = (@@SERVERNAME)

BEGIN 
exec msdb.dbo.rds_backup_database 
@source_db_name='MyDB',  
@overwrite_S3_backup_file=0,
@s3_arn_to_backup_to='arn:aws:s3:::MyBucket/Backups/FULL/MyDB'+@NOW+''
END'
```

Comment: As for how, the value of a parameter must be a literal or variable. Assign the value of the name you want to a variable, and then pass that as the parameter for `@s3_arn_to_backup_to`.

Comment: Why `DECLARE @NOW DATETIME` followed by `SET @NOW = (SELECT GETDATE())`? Why a subquery? Why not `DECLARE @NOW datetime = GETDATE()`?

Comment: Assuming you could even concatenate values in stored procedure parameters like that (you can't, btw), what format date are you expecting to append to the bucket key?

Comment: Thanks everyone, it works now, as @Larnu said, I have replaced the entire string in s3_arn_to_backup_to with a parameter